# select2 won't show me results after transforming data into the required format

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-select2

I use ajax call to fetch data from server and display the results via select2. The problem is that the fetched data is structured in a way that needs to be transformed for select2 to process it correctly.

When I transform data following their [documentation](https://select2.org/data-sources/formats), it won't show me the results.

The structure of the response:

```
{
  type1: [{result1}, {result2}, {result3}...],
  type2: [{result1}, {result2}, {result3}...],
  type3: [{result1}, {result2}, {result3}...]
}
```

Select2 expects data to be: `{"results": [{result1}, {result2}, {result3}...]}`

My code:

```js
    function formatParent(parent) {
      return parent.title || parent.text
    }

    Ember.$('#parent-select').select2({
      ajax: {
        url: '/api/parents/' + type,
        headers: headers,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: function (params) {
          let query = {
            q: params.term,
          }
          return query;
        },
        processResults: function (data) {

          const res = []
          
          for (let property in data) {
            if (data.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
              res.push({
                "text": property,
                "children": data[property]
              })
            }
          }

          return res
        }
      },
      width: 'resolve',
      theme: 'bootstrap',

      escapeMarkup: function (markup) {
        return markup;
      },
      minimumInputLength: 1,
      templateResult: formatParent,
      templateSelection: formatParent
    })
```

```html
      <select
        data-tags="true"
        data-placeholder={{placeholder}}
        id="parent-select"
        style="width: 100%;">
      </select>
```

When I transform the data as presented below the results appear in the dropdown without any problems:

```js
    function formatParent(parent) {
      return parent.title || parent.text
    }

    Ember.$('#parent-select').select2({
      ajax: {
        url: '/api/parents/' + type,
        headers: headers,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: function (params) {
          let query = {
            q: params.term,
          }
          return query;
        },
        processResults: function (data) {
          return {"results": data.type1}
        }
      },
      width: 'resolve',
      theme: 'bootstrap',

      escapeMarkup: function (markup) {
        return markup;
      },
      minimumInputLength: 1,
      templateResult: formatParent,
      templateSelection: formatParent
    })
```

Comment: It seems like you solved the problem on your own? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: select2 won't create option groups in case of ajax calls. I guess it's because they create options only if they're selected from the list (as they explain in their documentation https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax). They do it for performance reasons. I abandoned the idea of using optgroups in the end.